# Trying to select element from dropdown

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver-c#

After dropdown is expended how can I select an option from the dropdown which is in span

image of the expanded dropdown https://prnt.sc/k-rFIUa6Ixeo

HTML:

```
<span class="ant-select-selection-item" title="Mrs.">Mrs.</span>
```

C# code where dropdown is expended

```
WebElement dropDown = (WebElement)Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/main/section/form/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div"));
       dropDown.Click();
```

Note that title is changing in span element after another option is selected
so if we select first option title is Mr.

```
<span class="ant-select-selection-item" title="Mr.">Mr.</span>
```

short gif for better visual: https://gyazo.com/8093ced6107599ee7540490d4fba0cc2

Also hovering over dropdown options in the hmtl code above aria-activedescendant property is changing
so  for the option "MR" property is "rc_select_0_list_0", for option "Mrs" property is "rc_select_0_list_2" and so on,

for more details here is short gif https://gyazo.com/827fc0c4e1265b842301c87da6539e0c

Answer (score -1):

While developing automation frameworks, such scenarios are very common and can be automated in number of ways. One of the best approaches that we use especially for this scenario is by creating dynamic locators -
As mentioned in your case to select a value from drop down, utilize **text** instead of **title** in your xpath as mentioned below -

String str = "MR."
//span[text()="+str+"]

Case 2 - Xpath using title attribute -
//span[contains(@title, "Mr")]